# Keycloak - Dynamic Registration URLs

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-connect, keycloak-nodejs-connect

I trying to implement a way to efficiently manage several thousand users in a keycloak cluster somewhat automatically. I am wondering if there is a way for a user with higher credentials to generate a registration link containing url parameters that would then assign the appropriate role/group to a user who visited that link and created a new account?

Is this possible to do with keycloak out of the box? Thanks!